# WhatsApp Api - I ask for the number in the production and respond for the test number

Tags: whatsapi

Ashen. I would like some help.

Isso is locking the consumption of the WhatsApp API. Add new number. Therefore, when I send a message to the new number, I end up receiving a reply with the test number. I made a POST for any number through the product number - with Token and WhatsApp ID and I ended up receiving "OAuthException" - "The recipient's phone number is not on the permission list." How you are using the test number.

Any help?

Desired work: Ask for the product number and continue as same.

Comment: Could you show some code? What language are you using? Please add a language tag.

Comment: The English in this question is rather hard to follow. Could you get someone to proof-read it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to ensure that there is only one number, the production number registered to your WhatsApp business account ID. You can make this call via the Meta Graph API Explorer tool https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=101933159628482%2Fphone_numbers&version=v19.0

1. Make a get request to the endpoint `{whatsapp business id}/phone_numbers` to see which numbers are registered to that whatsapp business
2. Create a delete request to `{whatsapp business id}/{phone number to be removed}`

Please see the following Cloud API documentation for further understanding https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/cloud-api/reference/phone-numbers/

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Eu discovered.

Send deploy as {{WhatsApp_Id}} with your test number. ‍♀️

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).